# Сжатие видео-потока

Tags: linux

Здравствуйте.

Имеется небольшой сервер, имеется несколько сетевых интерфесов. В данном вопросе нам необходим только один: он смотрит в сеть и интернет, на нем висит белый IP. По запросу можно подключиться к видео-потоку (несколько каналов спутникового телевидения), управление потоками осуществляется протоколом IGMP. Качество потока хорошее, поэтому получается, в зависимости от канала, от 4Мб/с до 7Мб/с требуемая пропускная способность. Хочется мне сей поток завернуть обратно, только уже по HTTP, да только сжать бы его предварительно.

В данный момент работает утилита udpxy, работает по принципу IGMP-HTTP-Proxy. Подскажите, пожалуйста, чем бы сжать поток, хотя бы немного? И, если можно, с конкретным примером, а то найти описание для моего случая, например, с использованием того же MEncoder, не могу.
Т.е. видится два пути:

1. Принимать поток прямо с IGMP - сжимать - отправлять в HTTP.
2. Принимать поток с udpxy (HTTP) на localhost - отправлять в HTTP.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В промежуток IGMP-HTTP запихать VideoLAN.

Comment: А подробнее можно? Какие команды для запуска, что писать в конфиг?